# how to include php file contains 'use' command in another file with class

Tags: php, compiler-errors, facebook-php-sdk, alias, require

I have two files.

in the first file (Facebook.php) i take user data via Facebook (Facebook access token):

```
<?php

    require_once '../include/Config.php';
    require_once ( '../libs/facebook/autoload.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

    function getUserData($token){

      // init app with app id and secret
      FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( FB_APP_ID,FB_APP_SECRET ); //

      // If you already have a valid access token:
      $session = new FacebookSession($token); // 'access-token'

      // To validate the session:

      try {

           $session->validate();

      } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {

           // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
           echo $ex->getMessage();

      } catch (\Exception $ex) {

            // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
            echo $ex->getMessage();
      }

     if($session) {

             try {

                  $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray(); //(GraphUser::className());


                  // print profile data
                  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $user_profile, 1 ) . '</pre>';

                  return $user_profile;

              } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

                   echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                   echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
              }
      }

}

?>
```

and this is the second file for manage user data:

```
<?php

   require_once '../../../include/Facebook.php';

   class userManager {

       function __construct() {

    }

   /**
   * Get user data from facebook
   * @param user key
   * @return user data if exist else false
   */
   public function facebookSignIn($token){

        $fbUserData = getUserData($token);

        print_r($fbUserData);
   }
}
?>
```

in the second file i want to manage user data with a class but i think that my script don't run because the code lines in Facebook.php

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequest; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

causing an error in compiling time.

if I comment out these lines my script compiles but naturally doesn't retrieve facebook user data.

what is the right way to include 'facebook.php' in my class?
where am I wrong?

I apologize but I do not understand 'use' command and how I can use it.

If i include Facebook.php in a test file without class:

```
<?php

     require_once '../include/Facebook.php';

     $token = $_GET["token"];

     getUserData($token);
?>
```

the script run fine!

Comment: "*causing an error in compiling time*" - what error message do you get? Are we supposed to magically guess what it is? What version of PHP are you running on? `use` was introduced in 5.3.

Comment: up to 5.4 i know.. and the script run fine if i include and use it in a test file without class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found a solution for my problem. The problem is in the include lines in the first file because test.php is in different hierarchy path of second file.

I found the error using these lines of code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I apologize, but sometimes the most obvious things that are beyond our control.

thanks to everyone for the support

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself early on because I was not accustomed to using these commands.  `Use` commands have to be used within the same file that the functions relative to them are called.  So if `File A` contains the SDK initialization and you try the `use` commands then your API requests should work.  If `File B` is required or included within `File A` (or vice-versa), you must add the use commands within File B to initiate any Graph functions but they should still work.  It seems `use` commands only work within the file for which they are located and no others.

In your second file, add the `use` commands that you need and I believe you'll find it will work.  In your specific case, you may also need it within your function.